# Django/MySQL/Memcached for 10K user visitors

Tags: load-balancing, django, cpu-usage, cache

I'm currently using CentOS (512 RAM, Dual-core CPU) for my website. Here are the specs:

- Django 1.3.1
- Python 2.7.2
- Apache 2 with mod_wsgi 3.3
- MySQL 5 (about 5,000 records)
- Memcached (120 MB for running)
- Nginx for serving the static content

When my site has 2,000 visitors at the same time, the CPU usage reachs about 40% of total. And with 10K visitors, CPU is 90%-100%. The site is very slow. I've tried to cache in database but not working.

I could migrate to new larger server but it will be a waste. Because my site just reachs that large amount in 1-2 days of week.

Any idea for this? Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify why scaling the server would be a waste?  I'm a little surprised that an Python-backed Apache site on such a small server is performing that well.

Comment: Why not? I'm using Linode.com plan 1 for this site.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using [uWSGI](http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/) ?

According to my experience and [this website](http://nichol.as/benchmark-of-python-web-servers) , it beats all other setup when proxied behind nginx.

There are many blog posts regarding the setup of uWSGI behind nginx eg
http://www.jeremybowers.com/blog/post/5/django-nginx-and-uwsgi-production-serving-millions-page-views/